# jQuery function equal to href=#

Tags: jquery

Is there a jquery function that can make you go to #name, like you can if you make a link to href="#name", so I could on document ready directly go to #name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just change the location.hash, like this:

```
$(function() {
  window.location.hash = '#name'; //works with or without the # included
});
```

Though if you just hyperlink to the page, this is built-in browser behavior, for example going to `http://site.com/page.html#name` would have the same scroll-on-load effect.

Answer (score 1):

There is JavaScript:

```
window.location.hash = "#name"
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

Answer (score 1):

While a bit overkill you can try the scrollto plugin:

[Scrollto](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="goto" href="#this">go to this</a>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div id="this">this</div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

        $("#goto")[0].click();

    });
</script>
```

Or

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div id="this">this</div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

        $('<a href="#this">go to this</a>')[0].click();

    });
</script>
```